# Can't return body of http request

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

So I'm trying to return the body that I retrieve in OnResponse(). I can see in the debugger that the body is retrieved but doesn't get assigned to result and handleHttpRequest() returns ""? The only way that I can send the body String to parseJsonToObject() is by calling it in onResponse witch I don't want to because I want to use handleHttpRequest() for other JSON requests. What i want to do is to return the body in handleHttpRequest and call parseJsonToObject() in doInBackground().

My main question is why doesn't body get assigned to result?

inner class AsyncTaskHandleJson : AsyncTask() {

```
    override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String? {

        handleHttpRequest()

        return "";
    }

    private fun handleHttpRequest(): String? {
        val url = "https://www.noforeignland.com/home/api/v1/places/";
        val client = OkHttpClient();
        var result: String? = "";
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build();

       client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println(e)
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response?.body?.string();
                result = body;
                parseJsonToObjct(body)

            }
        })

        return result
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem is that client.newCall(request).enqueue is asynchronous and handleHttpRequest() returns before body gets assigned to result. I solved it by using client.newCall(request).execute() insted.

```
fun handleHttpRequest(url : String): String? {
        val client = OkHttpClient();
        var result: String? = "";
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        val response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if(response.isSuccessful){
            result = response?.body?.string();
        }else{
            println("HTTP Request FAILED")
        }
        return result
}
```